# Color output in the CIELab space

Tags: c++, colors, rgb

For the purpose of visualizing certain data, I'm supposed to utilize the colorings. Namely, the C++ code I have on disposal is outputting using cairo-graphics, and the function is based on RGB space. The data I work with should, on the other hand, utilize "certain slice" of the CIELab color space.

The question is: what would be the most appropriate way to do this with C++? Perhaps some conversion that might still rely on the RGB function provided by cairo (though I doubt this alternative, since RGB is device-dependent)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV has some built-in color conversions. You could use them, or use them as an inspiration for your own color conversion routine.
See [the doc about color conversion in OpenCV (cv::cvtColor)](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html)

One possible way to use it could be :

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
int main()
{
    cv::Mat imgRgb = cv::imread("file.bmp");
    cv::Mat imgLab;
    cv::cvtColor(imgRgb, imgLab, Cv::CV_BGR2Lab);

    //access Lab values
    int y = 50;
    int x = 20;
    double L = imgLab.at<double>(y,x)[0]; //beware the order : openCV treats images as matrixes, thus the y param come first
    double a = imgLab.at<double>(y,x)[1];
    double b = imgLab.at<double>(y,x)[2];   
}
```

Beware: I did not test or compile this code, this is just a draft.

Comment: Thanks. Given that the code I have on disposal is based on cairo-graphics functions generating colored pdf file, I guess there is a way to output a CIELab colored pdf output with the library you proposed? If not so, a suggestion on the library that allows this would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, pdf is *not* an image format. It is a format that can include images, texts, fonts (and the list goes on). And no, opencv does not handle pdf files. I suggest you take a look at the cimg library : it is easier to use than opencv, and it also does RGBtoLab conversions (see http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html). It can ouput to pdf, provided that you install imagemagick (imagemagick handles pdf file) : see http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__files__io.html

Answer (score 4):

I have compiled an tested the above. For future reference here is a function to convert RGB to CIELAB

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
Mat BGR2CIELab(Mat const &rgb_src)
{
    Mat imgLab;
    cvtColor(rgb_src, imgLab, CV_BGR2Lab);

    //access Lab values
    int y = 50;
    int x = 20;
    Vec3d pix_bgr = imgLab.ptr<Vec3d>(y)[x]; //beware the order : openCV treats images as matrixes, thus the y param come first
    double L = pix_bgr.val[0];
    double a = pix_bgr.val[1];
    double b = pix_bgr.val[2];

    return imgLab;
}
```

Comment: Your snippet runs successfully, but the value of L, a, b does not follow the constraints: 0<=L<=100, -127<=a<=127, -127<=b<=127.

Comment: I can't check it right now, but they are double values, so it is possible, that openCV puts them into another format; for example 0.0 < a < 1.0 etc. What intervals are your receiving? Generally the snippet relies on the correct implementation in OpenCV. So the next question would be: what version do you have in use?

Comment: I use OpenCV 2.4.8. Here's my result after running your code http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y442/lbkhanhvu/return_zps2062d06f.jpg. Can you take a look to see if it's right or wrong?